# Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android

```
public class CodeMainActicity extends Activity
{
private ExpandListAdapter ExpAdapter;
private ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> ExpListItems;
private ExpandableListView ExpandList;
public String[] groups = null;
public String[][] headers = null;
DisplayMetrics metrics;
int width;

public int GetDipsFromPixel(float paramFloat)
{
  return (int)(0.5F + paramFloat * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}

public ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> SetStandardGroups()
{
ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> localArrayList1 = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();
int i = 0;
if (i >=groups.length){
  return localArrayList1;
}
ExpandListGroup localExpandListGroup = new ExpandListGroup();
localExpandListGroup.setName(groups[i]);
ArrayList<ExpandListChild> localArrayList2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();
for (int j = 0; ; j++)
{
  if (j > 11){


  while (headers[i][j] == null)
  {
    localExpandListGroup.setItems(localArrayList2);
    localArrayList1.add(localExpandListGroup);
    i++;
    break;
  }
  }

  ExpandListChild localExpandListChild = new ExpandListChild();
  localExpandListChild.setName(headers[i][j]);
  localExpandListChild.setTag(null);
  localArrayList2.add(localExpandListChild);
}
}

  public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
{
this.groups = new String[11];
this.headers = ((String[][])Array.newInstance(String.class, new int[] { 14, 10 }));
this.groups[0] = "Data Types";
this.groups[1] = "Date Time";
this.groups[2] = "Regular Expressions";
this.groups[3] = "Class";
this.groups[4] = "Collections";
this.groups[5] = "Generics";
this.groups[6] = "Reflection";
this.groups[7] = "Security";
this.groups[8] = "Design Patterns";
this.groups[9] = "Thread";
this.groups[10] = "File Stream";
this.headers[0][0] = "Boxing and Unboxing";
this.headers[0][1] = "Complex Type";
this.headers[0][2] = "Enum";
this.headers[0][3] = "Tuple type";
this.headers[0][4] = "Hex to Int";
this.headers[0][5] = "Nullable Integer";
this.headers[0][6] = "Custom ToString()";
this.headers[0][7] = "Checked() and Unchecked()";
this.headers[0][8] = "Overflow";
this.headers[0][9] = "Char  methods";
this.headers[1][0] = "Get between Days";
this.headers[1][1] = "Add one week to current date";
this.headers[1][2] = "DateTime Compare";
this.headers[2][0] = "Email Validation";
this.headers[2][1] = "URL validation";
this.headers[2][2] = "Zipcode validation";
this.headers[3][0] = "Access modifiers";
this.headers[3][1] = "Inheritance";
this.headers[3][2] = "Interface";
this.headers[3][3] = "Method Overloading";
this.headers[3][4] = "Overriding";
this.headers[3][5] = "Abstract class";
this.headers[4][0] = "Array List";
this.headers[4][1] = "Hash Table";
this.headers[4][2] = "Dictionary";
this.headers[5][0] = "Simple Generic hierarchy";
this.headers[5][1] = "Generic IEnumerable";
this.headers[5][2] = "Generic Collection class";
this.headers[6][0] = "AppDomain Setup";
this.headers[6][1] = "Type.GetMethods";
this.headers[6][2] = "Assembly Version Information";
this.headers[7][0] = "MD5 encode";
this.headers[7][1] = "File Checksum";
this.headers[7][2] = "Password Encryption";
this.headers[8][0] = "Facade Pattern";
this.headers[8][1] = "Factory Pattern";
this.headers[8][2] = "Observer Pattern";
this.headers[8][3] = "Singleton Pattern";
this.headers[8][4] = "Adapter Pattern";
this.headers[9][0] = "Creating Thread";
this.headers[9][1] = "Asynchronous Calls";
this.headers[9][2] = "Mutex";
this.headers[10][0] = "Display File contents";
this.headers[10][1] = "Write to a file";
this.headers[10][2] = "Append to File";
super.onCreate(paramBundle);
requestWindowFeature(1);
setContentView(R.layout.codemainscreen);
Button localButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnhome);
this.ExpandList = ((ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.ExpList));
ExpListItems = SetStandardGroups();
this.ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(this, this.ExpListItems);
this.metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(this.metrics);
this.width = this.metrics.widthPixels;
this.ExpandList.setIndicatorBounds(this.width - GetDipsFromPixel(50.0F), this.width - GetDipsFromPixel(10.0F));
this.ExpandList.setAdapter(this.ExpAdapter);
```

Comment: Please post your logcat so that we can find which line is causing that

Comment: Your logCat please? Otherwise there will never be a possibility for us to find error for your codes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: 0. Read the 'How-to-ask'. 1. Provide a concise, short example reproducing the problem. 2. Describe what your problem is and *ask a question*. 3. Post a full stack trace.

Comment: and this one too: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html :)

Answer (score 1):

You have no condition in this loop

```
for (int j = 0; ; j++)
```

meaning that at after some while this has to crash.

```
for (int j = 0; /* add condition here */ ; j++) {
  if (j > 11){
    while (headers[i][j] == null) ... // or here ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Cheers!

Comment: +1 for taking the time to provide an answer while the OP didn't even bother to ask a question :)

Comment: And by the way: if **(j > 11)** { while (headers[i] **[j]** ... cannot possibly work in this case.